# retrieve data from table that has no model cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

How to retrieve data from table that has no model?
For example, I want to retrieve data from acos_Aros table so I can check the checked box that has _delete | _update | _view | _create is set to 1

Any help??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a model.  Voila.  (seriously)

Or, you can use any [Model's query() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) (doesn't have to be on the correct model) - it allows you to run a manually entered MySQL query.

Eg.

```
$arosAcosData = $this->AnyModel->query("SELECT * FROM acos_aros");
```

Comment: While it works I think it is bad style to use the `query` method of some unrelated model.

Comment: @dhofstet - I completely agree.  But I still think that's the solution.  Either make a model, or run a manual query.